# Visual glitch in HTML: dropdown menu and next privilege tracker

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, top-bar

The progress bar in the reputation tab overlaps with the site selection dropdown (see screenshots). Browser: Firefox 52.3.0.

[image: Dropdown not opened]
[image: Dropdown opened]